# Find number of elements whose id starts with

Tags: jquery, count, selector, startswith

Usually if you want to find the number of elements with an id you would just do:

`var count = $('#element').length;`

But I can't get it to work using a starts with selector:

`var customs = $('td[id^=customdata-]').length;`

`alert(customs);` always returns 0, even though there are several of these elements on the page. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<tr id="ssfa-file-3262-1">
  <td id="filetype-ssfa-file-3262-1">docx</td>
  <td id="filename-ssfa-file-3262-1">Employment Letter</span></a></td>
  <td id="customadata-0-ssfa-file-3262-1">2007</td>
  <td id="customadata-1-ssfa-file-3262-1">Thom Stark</td>
  <td id="mod-ssfa-file-3262-1">8:23 PM 03/15/2014</td>
  <td id="size-ssfa-file-3262-1">206.6k</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is DOM [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: Yes, wrapped in `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? [I can't reproduce the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/cTJx3/)

Comment: Checking now. Just added html.

Comment: Just an unrelated Google Maps error that's always there. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Does $('#element') give you an array of elements ?

Comment: $('#element') was just a generic example.

Comment: Anyway, I just tried switching from `$('td ...)` to $('input ...) and it works now (I have inputs in the TDs).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it didn't work for the TD element, but when I switched to the input selector (not shown in the HTML above, but the inputs are in the TDs), it worked for me.

```
var customs = $('input[id^="customdata-"][id$="'+sfx+'"]').length;
alert(customs);
```

The var `sfx` is the id of the table row (I'm iterating through an each function). So, not sure why input works and td doesn't, but at least it's doing what I need now.